# Filter Array but keep its properties in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to filter an array using `Array.prototype.filter()`. How can I do the following while keeping the custom object property of the array?

For example:

```js
const words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];
words.name = "Jupiter"; // custom property here

const result = words.filter(word => word.length > 6);
console.log(result.name); // this outputs "undefined"
```

This is a simplified example, in reality the extra property I have in the array is `.columns` from `d3.csv` for example:

```
dataframe = dataframe.filter(d => d.date <= limitDate);
// dataframe.columns is gone
```

Comment: do you want a new array  or just deleting unwanted items?

Comment: Why do you need that? Adding random properties to an array means you have to make A LOT of changes to support it. At best, you can make your own array class and change its [`@@Species`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/species) but do you *really* need that?

Comment: Or you can create an object `const data = {words: <an array>; name: 'Jupiter' }` and then filter the words

Comment: Even if JavaScript allows you to put custom properties on Array objects, it is an approach I do not recommend. This is *not* standard behavior and might confuse any developers in the future if they have to work with your code.

Comment: Everyone is commenting on why I am doing that, like I said in the question that's what d3 does with `d3.csv` and the columns properties. Not my design decision.

Comment: I'd suggest following @RubenHelsloot's comment and convert it to an object. Once you have the array from `d3.csv`, you can convert it before it all goes wrong. Take control over the code instead of trying to work around how someone else has implemented something.

Comment: I'd be happy to accept that as an answser @RubenHelsloot

Comment: Another option would be to add a `result.name = words.name` , that way you don't change the original data structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an object instead of an array and then safely assign attributes there:

```js
const words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];
const data = {
  words: words,
  name: "Jupiter"
};

data.words = data.words.filter(word => word.length > 6);
console.log(data.name);
```